# Java regexp substring extraction pattern

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, expression

I have this text:

```
<blockquote>1. тест1; тест2; </blockquote>
<blockquote>2. тест1; тест2; </blockquote>
<blockquote>1) тест1; тест2; </blockquote>
<blockquote>2) тест1; тест2; </blockquote>
<blockquote>1. 1) тест1; тест2; </blockquote>
<blockquote>1) 1. тест1; тест2; </blockquote>
<blockquote>1. тест </blockquote>
```

Could u give me expression, using that I can extract тест1; тест2; to variable in any of this strings? тест1; тест2; - is cyrilic. so for extract тест I need to use ([\p{IsCyrillic}]*) expression.

```
String pattern = "(.*)<blockquote>1. ([\\p{IsCyrillic}]*) </blockquote>(.*)";
```

work only for first variant. What will be expression for any of this variant? (or may be u can give me particular expression for each variant of string?

Comment: I don't think that this regex really works. `1; ` and `2; ` are not matched by `\p{IsCyrillic}`.

Comment: with "(.*)<blockquote>1. ([\\p{IsCyrillic}]*) </blockquote>(.*)" I can extract only тест, not тест1; тест2;.

Comment: you right. Could u give me right form of expression for my text?

Comment: You need to define first what exactly you do want to match - what else besides cyrillic letters is allowed in a match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For all strings in your original post: -**

```
String pattern = "(.*)<blockquote>[\\d[\\.\\)]\\s]+([[\\p{IsCyrillic}][\\d\\;\\s]+]+) </blockquote>(.*)";
```

**For your new requirement string as given below, use this pattern.: -**

```
String str = "<blockquote>1. тест </blockquote><blockquote>2. 1) ветка; метрика </blockquote>";

String p = "[(.*)<blockquote>[\\d[\\.\\)]\\s]+([[\\p{IsCyrillic}][\\d\\;\\s]+]+) </blockquote>(.*)]+";
```

**OK, to match and return `тест, ветка; метрика` all three in the above string, here's the code: -**

```
String str = "<blockquote>1. тест </blockquote><blockquote>2. 1) ветка; метрика </blockquote>";

Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(тест)|(ветка;)|(метрика)");

Matcher matcher = pattern1.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
    System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

But, since you are just matching a `fixed` string, you don't really need a `regex`. You can just use regular `String` class method. Use `String.substring`, `String.indexOf` methods to find your string. Real power of `Regex` is in matching several strings on one pattern.

Comment: The middle of that doesn't look right.  It only matches a single Cyrillic character in each word.

Comment: I check it on this text: <blockquote>1. тест </blockquote><blockquote>2. 1) ветка; метрика </blockquote> and it return only ветка; метрика

Comment: Of course one regex made for a particular pattern will fail at others.. You need to specify exactly what all patterns you want to match??

Comment: ok, if I have text : <blockquote>1. тест </blockquote><blockquote>2. 1) ветка; метрика </blockquote> what expression returns тест?

Comment: You want it to return just тест? Then why not just compare with it?? You don't need a Regex then..

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 2
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
 at openones.stardictcore.StarDict.main(StarDict.java:305)

Comment: Well for me it worked for: - `String str = "<blockquote>1. тест </blockquote><blockquote>2. 1) ветка; метрика </blockquote>";`

Comment: really I need to return тест; ветка; метрика (all three) but I think it is not possible. so I need to return just тест/

Comment: I have just checked.. It worked.. What expression are you matching with this pattern?? (Talking about the 2nd one where you are getting error)..

Comment: I trying to create application, that give translation of the word from StarDict dictionary. The problem is that word meaning field for every word is very complex. It have many meany tags and meanings. So I want to extract only one useful meaning. So i need exactly regex, not code.

Comment: `Pattern.compile("(тест)|(ветка;)|(метрика)");` - this statement contained the `Regex` - `(тест)|(ветка;)|(метрика)`.. But to get the matching words back, you need that code..

Comment: Your first program code is return  ветка; метрика for String str = "<blockquote>1. тест </blockquote><blockquote>2. 1) ветка; метрика </blockquote>"; How can I change it to return тест instead ветка; метрика. Your first expression is practical ok for me. but it return second meaning instaed first.

Comment: Which code?? the Last one?  To get just тест, match just with it - `Pattern.compile("тест")`.. You really don't need regex, when your pattern is fixed..

Comment: I find how to take your expression work. I use String pattern = "(.*)<blockquote>[\\d[\\.]\\s]+([[\\p{IsCyrillic}][\\d\\;\\s]+]+)</blockquote>(.*)"; Some why if i use [\\d[\\.\\)]\\s] expression match only 1) not 1. Thanks. And one more. could u tell me some tool to create expressions?

Comment: `[\\d[\\.\)]\\s]` will certainly match either `1.` or `1)`.. I don't know why you are not able to match.. Mine is working fine...  When we write something like `[aB]`, it means match either `a` or `B`..

Comment: So, `[\\d[\\.\\)]\\s]`, will match either `1.\\s` or `1)\\s`.. Check the inner square bracket..  It says match `either . or )` after the digit..

Comment: What tool do you want?? Do, you want something that will automatically create `Regex` for you?? Then let me tell you, there is n such tool..

Comment: As for API, check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html classes that are used widely for `Regex`

Comment: No, tool to help me check it. some why http://regexpal.com/ didnt work with your expression

Comment: Did you see that, that's a `JavaScript` Regex checking tool??

Comment: It's written right at the top.. `regexpal 0.1.4 — a JavaScript regular expression tester`.. Don't use that tool, or any tool to check any regex.. You can better write a program to test it..

Comment: could u give me email? I will give u 2 real text. I dont know, where is mistake.

Comment: It's in my Profile: - `rohitjain.pce2011@gmail.com`

Comment: You regex just matches тест1, ветка and метрика. I think he wants to get the text within the blockquotes. If it'd have been to search just these strings, then he could have just use a string search to get the index.

Comment: @Shashwat. haha, not taking it personal :) Actually mine downvote was viable, in that answer. You should remove your first code from there, so that I can remove it. That code is not needed.

Comment: @Shashwat. Well, I'm not upvoting. May be someone else liked your answer. Congrats. :)

Comment: @Shashwat. I think you should remove your comments now, as I have removed mine. It will feel wierd if someone sees you talking to yourself. ;) :P

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your exact requirements.  Here is a fairly simplistic modification that assumes the numbering at the beginning can be any combination of spaces, right parentheses, dots, and numbers.

```
String pattern = 
 "(.*)<blockquote>[\\s\\.\\)\\d]+([\\p{IsCyrillic}\\;\\d\\s]*)</blockquote>(.*)";
```

Update: also edited so that the middle section matches semicolons, digits, and whitespace.

*Update 2: after reading the discussions in the comments, I'm no longer sure of what is needed, but what this does is match the entire middle section after the numbering.  The matched section can be any combination of Cyrillic characters, semicolons, numbers, and whitespace (as long as it doesn't start with a number).*

Comment: this expression is not ok for <blockquote>1. слово </blockquote>

Comment: You should replace: - [\\s\\.\\)\\d] by [\\d\\.\\)\\s] after first <blockquote>.. As its `1.\\s `

Comment: it also works. could u add for this expression fragment to match <blockquote>1. тест </blockquote>

Comment: @Jain, that should not make a difference, because order doesn't matter within a character class.

Comment: @sperr0w, I'm not sure how it fails. I think the question may not have been well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to retrieve `тест1` and `тест2`. Then you can just perform string search using `String.substring()` and `String.indexOf()` functions. No need of regex in that case.

But if the tags can contain different strings, then you can use the following regex.

`(?<= ).*?(?=(;| ))`

This regex will select the strings separately inside the blockquote tag.

```
<blockquote>1. тест1; тест2; </blockquote>
<blockquote>2. тест1; тест2; </blockquote>
<blockquote>1) тест1; тест2; </blockquote>
<blockquote>2) тест1; тест2; </blockquote>
<blockquote>1. 1) тест1; тест2; </blockquote>
<blockquote>1) 1. тест1; тест2; </blockquote>
<blockquote>1. тест </blockquote>
```

This will select

```
тест1 тест2
тест1 тест2
тест1 тест2
тест1 тест2
1) тест1 тест2
1. тест1 тест2
тест
```

for all the tags respectively.

If you want to remove `1)` and `1.` from 5th and 6th tags, then format your string accordingly.

But if you have all the tags in the same line, then it will select those tags too. You can filter them out by checking if the matched string starts with a `<`.

Answer (score -2):

The pattern here look quite good and should work. However, sometimes I find it easier to do stuff like this step by step, e.g.:

```
  public static void main(String[] args){

    String[] testStrings = { "<blockquote>1. тест1; тест2; </blockquote>",
      "<blockquote>2. тест1; тест2; </blockquote>",
      "<blockquote>1) тест1; тест2; </blockquote>",
      "<blockquote>2) тест1; тест2; </blockquote>",
      "<blockquote>1. 1) тест1; тест2; </blockquote>",
      "<blockquote>1) 1. тест1; тест2; </blockquote>" };

    for (String testString : testStrings){

      String result = testString
        .replace("<blockquote>", "")
        .replace("</blockquote>", "")
        .replaceAll("\\d\\.|\\d\\)", "")
        .trim();

      System.out.println(result);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I need expression, not code fragment. really I have a very big texp from StarDict Dictionary article.

Comment: This is a lot less efficient, and there are also potential problems.    Sure, it works on the example data, but what does the rest of the data look like? You are no longer enforcing that the inner characters are Cyrillic, nor are you checking that things appear in the correct order.  And if there is stuff outside the `<blockquote>` tags, you will present that as part of the result.  A Regex is the right tool for this job.

Comment: I see, however I just wanted to mention that regex are not always a good idea, sometimes it's easier to write and maintain a code fragment that does it step by step. Besides, this looks like he parsing XML or HTML and maybe one should use a full blown parser here.